# Change seaborn boxenplot outline color

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting a violin plot, and I wanted to overlay a boxen plot instead of the default box plot. I was able to get it working like so, where `y` is a list of values, and `x` is a list such that `x[i]` is the category of `y[i]`:

```py
violinplot(x=x, y=y, color='red', scale='width', bw=0.3, inner=None)
boxenplot(x=x, y=y, color=point_color, width=0.1)
```

[image]

I'm pretty happy with the results, but it would be great if I could change the outline of the boxen plot to be the same color as the outline of the violin plot instead of white. I can't seem to figure out how to change the boxen plot outline, though, and it doesn't seem to be in the documentation. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Niema Moshiri, you can do it through set_style function with parameter 'patch.edgecolor': 'red'.

Like this

1. `sns.set_style(style="white",rc= {'patch.edgecolor': 'yellow'})`
2. `sns.violinplot(data=data, color='red', scale='width', bw=0.3, inner=None)
   sns.boxenplot(data=data, color="grey",width=0.`

[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-10 at 1 01 33 AM]

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is great, thank you! This works, but my concern is that it seems like a global change. It would be great if there was some way to just change the outline of this specific call to `sns.boxenplot`. Do you happen to know how to do that, e.g. via some parameter to `boxenplot` or some iteration over the return value or something?

Comment: @Niema Moshiri I will dig into documentation more, couldn't find a parameter for it.
But you can disable the edge color when you don't need it anymore in plots by setting 
`rc ={patch.force_edgecolor=False }`

Which will disable it for coming plots. Not the best solution but, works for now.

Hope it helps.